# How do you retrieve a position of a word from a list?

Tags: python

I have a list and I need to retrieve the position of the word, so far I  have, the word I want to print positions is sea

```
Sentence = [she , sells , sea , shells ,on , the, sea , shore]
print (sentence.find(sea))
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Honestly, this is a pretty simple question with a simple solution.  I don't think it deserves downvotes or to be closed except for the fact that it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `index()` function of lists:

```
Sentence = ["she" , "sells" , "sea" , "shells" ,"on" , "the", "sea" , "shore"]
print Sentence.index("sea")
```

The index of lists is zero-based, therefore the result is `2`.